# Mysql select different database after connecting to one

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to re-select a database, I have two databases, one for VB, one for a custom CMS. They're both connected, however I only store a small amount of user data on the CMS one and need to be able to retrieve the user information from VB table.

So heres the process,

1. I have a DB object already connected, and selected the CMS database
2. I load up a function to get the user data
3. I reselect the database via

   mysql_select_db("xxxx_xxxvb", $this->mysql_con);
4. When I execute the function, it returns the data from the CMS's user table, and not VB

Anyone got any ideas why?

Thank you

Comment: Does `mysql_error()` return anything right after the call to `mysql_select_db`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to open two connections

```
$con1 = mysql_connect('your', 'db', 'info');
$con2 = mysql_connect('your', 'db', 'info');

mysql_select_db("xxx_xxxcms", $con1);
mysql_select_db("xxx_xxxvb", $con2);
```

and see if it works. Don't forgot to use queries like

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'user'", $con2);
```

Comment: Nope, selected exact same db for some reason, cms not vb

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius: you did something wrong. My code works great

Comment: You forgot mysql_error, so did I :) Turns out I forgot to add permission for the user to use the other DB, works now, thanks!